# Multiple Roles for a User belonging to multiple Organizations

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, servicestack

I am working on a web application where a User belongs to multiple Organizations. The  Role to be used is determined by what Organization the User is currently viewing the web application as. Once logged in, the User has the ability to easily switch between their different Organizations that they belong to. For some Organizations, a User may be an ADMIN while just being a MEMBER in others.

In ServiceStack, what is the best way to accomplish this? Would it make sense to leverage the `Dictionary<string, string> Meta` property of the `Authenticate` Request DTO? Or creating a custom `AuthProvider` that overrides the `IsAuthorized` method? Or a different technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to assign custom `org1.Admin`, `org2.Member` Roles or permissions, that way you can use ServiceStack's built-in `[RequiresRole]` to validate access.

The bespoke alternative is to create a [Custom UserSession](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack) and the appropriate typed metadata collections to your `AuthUserSession` object. Then use a custom  [RequestFilterAttribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes#request-filter-attributes) to check the UserSession has the appropriate access.

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you. Following your suggestions, I was able to accomplish what I needed to.